# How to structure php code to populate 280 fields in a form if a record exists in mysql

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

I have a html form with about 280 text, radios and select dropdown fields.  I have to capture a lot of information about people's outgoings.  Eg. Who their gas and electricity providers are, how much they pay, the rates, their bank accounts, loan accounts, broadband etc.  The list of fields sounds huge, but it's laid out in tabs and it isn't too overwhelming and people don't have to fill in all of it anyway.

I present the blank form to the new user and then post every field value (blank or not) to the mysql dbase on the first submit.
The problem is.. how do I retrieve all that data and put it into the form the next time?  I'm out of my depth with elegant solutions, so I guess I'd do a foreach loop through each database record retrieved and save it to a variable, but then I have to insert the 280 field values into the fields using an  statement in the value="xxx" for each field, something like:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="loan1name" class="col-lg-5 control-label text-right">Loan Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="loan1name" placeholder="Car loan" value=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($loan1name) ?>>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I had 10 fields it wouldn't matter, but 280 is unmanageable doing it that way.  Is there any other way? Do I need to go about this a completely different way? Does it make sense to duplicate the form and use one for the blank one which does the INSERT, then another for the pre-populated version for the UPDATE query?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I just know there must be a better way, but I can't find any answer on here or anywhere else.
It doesn't seem simple because the fields are quite varied and one is even a set of pictures as a radio button sequence (it's pictures of types of locks you have on your front door - for your home insurance).

Comment: If you have mixed elements like inputs, radios, checkboxes, selects you can populate them when you have to do an update, using ajax for example depending on what they are, for example you can add a specific class or data attribute to make a difference between elements

Comment: Now the real question is - why on this lovely Earth do you have 280 fields? You said it yourself - if you had 10 - that'd be excellent. I smell some terrible decision while doing the modelling. We're programmers, that means we're lazy and we're making these poor dumb machines to do the work for us - yes, there's always a way to do less and have the computer do the heavy work. It all stems from *how* you structured your data, how you pulled it out and how you named everything. And that's what we can't see.

Comment: This sounds like an **[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/360627)** to me. (Agreeing with @N.B.)

Comment: Well that's a fair question.  The data is related to a wide range of outgoings people have.  So for example, a bunch of fields are: Bank account name 1, Bank account type 1 - Savings, everyday account etc, Bank balance 1.  Loan account provider 1, Loan balance 1 etc, Gas and electricity providers, credit cards, the list goes on.  That's why there's 280 fields.  There's a huge amount of information to capture!  I may have bitten off more than I can chew though.  I know enough to get myself into trouble thinking of what is possible, but not enough to be able to work out an elegant solution!

Comment: @shmaxnow if these are dynamic for every user, why not store the fields in a single array (json encoded) to store in a single field and then loop through the $keys=>$values to get all the information for each user? Instead of having so many fields. Just set the array keys to the name of the field and the value to the actual value of the field for each user. You could even do a different field for each type of element, and then you know exactly what to loop through. For example, a table header called "text-fields" with a json array `["Name":"Test","Bank":"Test2"]`

Answer (score 0):

Mysql usually return an associative array. You can then use the key/value pairs in this array to dynamically create your form.

```
<?php foreach($fields AS $name => $value){ ?>
    <input type="text" name="<?= $name ?>" value="<?= $value ?>" /><br />
<?php } ?>
```

**Note**: The downside is that you are still missing the label and placeholder of each input. Also, they would all be text input.